# Put many pictures into one div with specific size

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have created an app which creates lots of pictures with `new Image()` according to the context.

I want to put all my photos into one specific div, this div will always have the same size: 90% of the screen.

When I hover over a picture, the real picture will appear.

The photos width have to be resized according to the number of photos.

This is an example of what I want to do:

[image: example]

Every color represents a different picture.

This is when I hover a picture (here: the red one):

[image: example-hover]

I have absolutely no idea of how to make this. If you have an idea or a clue for one of these things you're welcome to help me! Thanks.

Comment: You can try adding event listeners on each picture element, addEventListener, then use `mouseover` to show the picture element and `mouseout` to hide it again

Answer (score 1):

when you add the image to div, you could to this.

```
$("div > img").css("width",($("div > img").length/100)+"%");
```

I supposed you are using jquery, if not at least you have a better idea. 
(Apply a width for every image inside, width is number of images/100 percent).

Answer (score 0):

You can use onmouseover and onmouseout event to grab the image element you want to select.
Adding event listeners to all images would be potentially bad idea with memory leak if you don't handle them carefully and there are a lot of images. I think you can add event listener to window or document and find out the source element(target) of mouseover and mouseout event when hovering.

```
window.onmouseover = function(event) {
       event = event || window.event;
       const srcEl = event.srcElement || event.target;
       // use srcEl for further actions (get image src url or whatever)
}
```

After that, you get the image url by 'src' attribute of image tag to update the main hero image.

Also as for performance when there lots of images, I advise you to use images as background of divs with css instead of img tag. They are faster than tag img. (why? images can be scale if img tag, although backgrounds can't be).